# Moving a directory in CLI using mv but only rename the file

Tags: macos, interface, command, command-line-interface, line

I can't seem to move a Brazil dir from it's South_America directory to Americas.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgW9B.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a Brazil directory in Americas and move all the files from the original Brazil into new Brazil.

mkdir Brazil
mv Brazil/*.* Americas/Brazil/*